# Trouble importing a module with radiobuttons - python

Tags: python, import, module, tkinter, radio-button

Hi I have made a program that runs various other programs. I import the module and it works fine for programs that don't have radiobuttons involved. The programs with radiobuttons work fine when they are ran by themselves. When they are ran through my menu program, the radiobuttons do not give the IntVar values. Anybody have any ideas on how to fix this? The modules are my ow programs but they all use Tkinter. Here is the code for the menu:

```
from Tkinter import *
def cmd():
    if var.get() == 1:
        import animal_age_calculator
        animal_age_calculator.createDisplay()
    if var.get() == 2:
        import temperatureCalculator
        temperatureCalculator.createDisplay()
    if var.get() == 3:
        import calculator
        calculator.createDisplay()
    if var.get() == 4:
        import currencyConverter
        currencyConverter.createDisplay()

def createDisplay():
    global var
    root = Tk()
    root.title('Calculator')

    title = Label(root, text='Please Select which Calculator you would like to use',      font=50)
    title.grid(row=0, column=0)

    calcType = Frame(root)
    calcType.grid(row=1, column=0)
    var = IntVar()
    animal = Radiobutton(calcType, text='Animal Age Calculator', variable=var, value=1)
    animal.pack()

    tempConverter = Radiobutton(calcType, text='Temperature Calculator', variable=var, value=2)
    tempConverter.pack()

    calc = Radiobutton(calcType, text='Calculator', variable=var, value=3)
    calc.pack()

    currency = Radiobutton(calcType, text='Currency Converter', variable=var, value=4)
    currency.pack()

    select = Button(root, text='Go', command=cmd)
    select.grid(row=2, column=0)

    root.mainloop()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    createDisplay()
```

Here is the code for one of the radiobutton programs:

```
from Tkinter import *
def convert(temperature):
    global var4
    a = var4.get()
    print(str(a))
    if a == 1:
        print 'test2'
        display.delete(1.0, END)
        finalTemp = int(temperature)*1.8+32
        finalTemp = round(finalTemp, 1)
        display.insert(INSERT, finalTemp)
    if a == 2:
        display.delete(1.0,END)
        finalTemp = int(temperature)-32/1.8
        finalTemp = round(finalTemp, 1)
        display.insert(INSERT, finalTemp)

def createDisplay():
    global display, var4
    root = Tk()
    root.title('Temperature Converter')
    root.resizable(width=False, height=False)

    title = Label(root, text="Welcome to the temperature converter", font=36)
    title.grid(row=0, column=1, columnspan=3)

    selTemp = LabelFrame(root, text="Please select your temperature")
    selTemp.grid(row=1, column=2)

    temp = Scale(selTemp, orient=HORIZONTAL, sliderlength=20, from_=0, to=250,  length=250, command=convert)
    temp.pack()
    temperature = temp.get()

    displayFrame = LabelFrame(root, text="Your converted temperature is")
    displayFrame.grid(row=1, column=3)
    display = Text(displayFrame, width=6, height=1)
    display.pack()

    var4 = IntVar()
    tempType = LabelFrame(root, text='Please select your temperature you would like to convert')
    tempType.grid(row=1, column=1)
    celcius = Radiobutton(tempType, text="Celcius", variable=var4, value=1)
    celcius.pack()
    fahrenheit = Radiobutton(tempType, text="Fahrenheit", variable=var4, value=2)
    fahrenheit.pack()
    root.mainloop()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    createDisplay()
```

Comment: Can you give some example code? Also please give details of what modules you're using.

Comment: the modules are my own python code but they all use Tkinter.

Comment: That's a good start but you're probably going to have to give some example code for people to work with in trying to solve your problem :) If you're getting errors then if you could also provide the Traceback that would be useful.

Comment: I have edited the original post with the code.

Comment: no errors occur, it just doesn't work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The crux of the problem is that you're creating two instances of `Tk`. You can't do that. Tkinter is designed for you to only ever create a single instance of Tk at any one time. Your modules should create instances of `Toplevel` rather than instances of `Tk`, and they should not create a new event loop when the module is imported.

Comment: I will try this now... if what you are saying is true why is it that the programs without radiobuttons work fine?

Comment: @DecStanley: It's impossible to say for certain, but I would guess it's because these other programs don't use IntVars or StringVars. The problem is perhaps a bit deeper than that, too deep to answer in a comment box. Suffice it to say, Tkinter wasn't designed to have two instances of Tk running at the same time in the same process.